# Fetch single user data from box

Tags: box-api, box

I am using box api integration to my app, I am facing an issue with fetching a single user data, I am an enterprise admin and I am getting all the users list when I use `GET /users` api. How can I take the single user out of this when I pass the login param of the User object. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch a single user by using the `filter_term` query parameter to match all or part of the user's login ([docs](https://docs.box.com/reference#get-all-users-in-an-enterprise)):

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users?filter_term=prats
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Response:

```
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "entries": [
      {
        "type": "user",
        "id": "123456",
        "name": "prats",
        "login": "prats@stackoverflow.com",
        ...
      }
   ]
}
```

Be aware that `filter_term` matches the beginning of the login string. If you have multiple users with names that start the same way, e.g. `prats` and `prats2`, the above request will return both of them. To prevent this, specify the entire login, or simply append an `@` to the end of the `filter_term` value:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users?filter_term=prats@
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: can the `filter_term` take wildcards? What is the format?

Comment: No wildcards, only partial matches. I updated the 'docs' link --- see there for more info.